# ¿Cómo detectar si la tecla bloq mayus está activada?

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una aplicación PHP, el asunto es que estoy trabajando con la seguridad y una de las cositas para la comodidad del usuario es que antes de ingresar la contraseña, el campo del password le diga si la tecla <kbd>bloq mayus</kbd> está activada o no, para que puedan poner correctamente su contraseña.

Aquí esta el código que he intentado:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function isMayus(input){
     kCode=input.keyCode?input.keyCode:input.which;
     sKey=input.shiftKey?input.shiftKey:((kCode==16)?true:false);
     if(((kCode>=65&&kCode<=90)&&!sKey)||((kCode>=97&&kCode<=122)&&sKey ))
        alert('El Bloq Mayus está activado.');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Por favor adjunta lo que has intentado o entodo caso, el código en el que intentas hacer la función. Te ayudaría leer [ask] y el [tour]

Comment: Esto es una tarea para el FrontEnd , por ejemplo con JavaScript ;)

Comment: PHP funciona en el lado del servidor, donde recibirás los resultados del formulario. Lo que es el formulario en sí estará en el lado del cliente y deberá controlarse con JavaScript como menciona otro usuario. De hecho, el código que compartes es en JavaScript y no en PHP, por lo que me imagino que es eso lo que buscas.

Comment: Estas usando jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucione el problema con este codigo

```
<script> 
$('[type=password]').keypress(function(e) {
var $password = $(this),
  tooltipVisible = $('.tooltip').is(':visible'),
  s = String.fromCharCode(e.which); 
  if ( s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey ) {
if (!tooltipVisible)
  $password.tooltip('show');
} else {
if (tooltipVisible)
  $password.tooltip('hide');
}
$password.blur(function(e) {
$password.tooltip('hide');
});
});
</script>
```

y poniendo esto dentro del html:

```
<input type="password" id="passwd" name="con" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" class="form-control" class="input-block-level" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="manual" data-title="La tecla Bloq Mayús está activada" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a" autocomplete="off" required>
```

Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Desde este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript) de SO en inglés, sugieren estas soluciones, prueba con ellas la que más te convenga:

---

**Usando `getModifierState`**

Aquí se usa la función [**`getModifierState`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState) que detectará un evento de tipo [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) que capturará el estado de distintas teclas como:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- <kbd>AltGraph</kbd>
- <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>
- <kbd>Control</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> *(Android)*
- <kbd>Meta</kbd>
- <kbd>NumLock</kbd>
- <kbd>OS</kbd> *(Windows & Linux)*
- <kbd>ScrollLock</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Aquí el ejemplo:

```
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( event ) {
  var mayus = event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState( 'CapsLock' );
  console.log( mayus ); //que será verdadero cuando presiones Bloq Mayus
  if(mayus)
       alert('Bloq Mayus está activado.');
});
```

---

**Si usas Jquery**

```
$('#password').keypress(function(e) { 
    var s = String.fromCharCode( e.which );
    if ( s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey ) {
        alert('Bloq Mayus está activado.');
    }
});
```

---

**Otra función en javascript**

```
function isBloqMayus(e){

    e = (e) ? e : window.event;

    var charCode = false;
    if (e.which) {
        charCode = e.which;
    } else if (e.keyCode) {
        charCode = e.keyCode;
    }

    var shifton = false;
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        shifton = e.shiftKey;
    } else if (e.modifiers) {
        shifton = !!(e.modifiers & 4);
    }

    if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122 && shifton) {
        return true;
    }

    if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90 && !shifton) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

De todas formas puedes dar un vostazo a las otras soluciones propuestas en el [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript)